# ImportError: cannot import name 'Monitor' from 'gym.wrappers'

Tags: python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have just created a new environment with gym installation. I am just getting started with Atari games but am getting an import error for my below code -

```
import gym
env = gym.make('FrozenLake-v1')
videosDir = './RL_videos'
env = gym.wrappers.Monitor(env, videosDir )
```

Error traceback -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/home/Ash/RL/code/rl03-Videos.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gym.wrappers import Monitor
ImportError: cannot import name 'Monitor' from 'gym.wrappers' (/Users/home/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gym/wrappers/__init__.py)
(pytorch) ash@Ash-Air code % python rl03-Videos.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/home/Ash/RL/code/rl03-Videos.py", line 15, in <module>
    env = gym.wrappers.Monitor(env, videosDir )
AttributeError: module 'gym.wrappers' has no attribute 'Monitor'
```

Version -

Python 3.9

Gym 0.23.1

I have ffmpeg installed via brew as well as pip

Comment: how do you install gym?

Answer (score 5):

`Monitor` is deprecated, you must use

```
from gym.wrappers.record_video import RecordVideo
```

and use it in this way

```
env = gym.make('CartPole-v1', render_mode="rgb_array")
env = RecordVideo(env, './video',  episode_trigger = lambda episode_number: True)
env.reset()
    
# your code...
```

Comment: how do you install gym?

Comment: Thanks! It worked with Python 3.10 on google Colab, as of Oct 20, 2023.